# java script query how to filter a table on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with five input text for filters as showing in this jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/607y6qdx/2/

I want to filter the information in the table whenever there is a text inside one of these filters and when the users clicks enter.

i already simulated the enter click like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#transactionIDFilter, #messageTypeFilter, #timestampFilter, #messageTextFilter, #originFilter, #destinationFilter ')
        .keypress(function (e) {
            var key = e.which;
            if (key == 13) // the enter key code
            {
                alert('Oh boy');
                return false;
            }
        });
});
```

but i couldn't filter the rows.

could you help me please. i am new to js

Comment: You can either choose a library that already handles this, or do it manually  using jquery .filter method to filter the rows of the table

Answer (score 0):

So the logic you need to follow is

1. Fetch the value of the input field and get the index of the input
   field in which user has pressed enter.
2. Traverse across all the
3. Pick td of the index fetched from the firt step.
4. If the typed value exists in the fetched td then show the entire row or else hide the entired row.

Here is the code which may help:

```
$(
        '#transactionIDFilter, #messageTypeFilter, #timestampFilter, #messageTextFilter, #originFilter, #destinationFilter')
        .keypress(function (e) {
        var key = e.which;
        if (key == 13) // the enter key code
        {
            $val = $(this).val();
            $el = $(this).closest("td");
            var index = $("td").index($el);
            $("tr").not(".fixed").each(function () {
                $elinner = $(this).find("td").eq(index);
                if ($elinner.html().indexOf($val) != -1) {
                    $(this).show();
                } else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/607y6qdx/7/

Comment: your code works just on the cell that i click enter on. For instance, if the first filter has words, and the second filter has words, and i click enter in the second filter, you won't apply any filter that exists in the first cell